# How to write current date into Postgres with Python?

Tags: python, postgresql

I cannot write date into Postgres column with type 'date'.

I use this code:

```
import datetime
import pytz

now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow"))
sql = "INSERT INTO questions (date) VALUES (%s, %s)" \
                      % (datetime.date(now.year, now.month, now.day))
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Also, I tried this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO questions (date) VALUES (%s, %s)" \
                      % (datetime.datetime.now())
cursor.execute(sql)
```

But I have the same error:

```
psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: ╬╪╚┴╩└:  ёЄюысхЎ "date" шьххЄ Єшя date, р т√Ёрцхэшх - integer
LINE 1: INSERT INTO questions (id, date) VALUES (10, 2020-12-04)
                                                     ^
HINT:  ╧хЁхяш°шЄх т√Ёрцхэшх шыш яЁхюсЁрчєщЄх хую Єшя.
```

Can you help me, what's the problem?

Comment: Do not insert your values into the sql string. (There's good reasons for never doing this; google sql injection...)

Try instead:

 cursor.execute(sql, (datetime.datetime.now(), (datetime.datetime.now()))

Comment: Please check the docs https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries.  As paul comments, you should not use string formatting/interpolation to create SQL queries unless you understand all the rules around quoting variables.  Chances are postgres thinks `2020-12-04` is an arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` type is actually a custom type of the `String`. So date value should be string.

Try this (which added 2 `'` characters.):

```
sql = "INSERT INTO questions (id, date) VALUES (%s, '%s')" % (datetime.datetime.now())
```

Note: Check the paul's comment also!

Comment: See the comments on the answer about not inserting values directly into SQL strings. This can be a very severe security vulnerability.